# OAuth to authenticate my app and allow it to access data at Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, mobile, oauth

I have a web server at Google App Engine and I want to protect my data. My mobile app will access the server to get this data.
The idea is with OAuth authenticate my app, when it requests some data via REST. After the first authentication, the app will always be able to access the content.
I don't want user's data, as Google Account or Facebook. My mobile app will assume the role of user to my services.
Is it possible? Someone has another idea to create these structure?
I'm not using Google End Point and my GAE is developed with Python.

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Mario Jorge Valle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you say you're not using Endpoints, but not why. It's likely the solution you want, as it's designed precisely for same-party (i.e. you own the backend and the client application) use cases, which is exactly what you've described.

Comment: Me and a friend were thinking about create the authentication without the Endpoint, and after add it as a wrapper in our backend.
How can we protect our data on App engine? I mean, if we don't have an authentication in our backend, an user can access our data outside of the mobile app, is it correct?
Do you suggest another way to protect our App Engine Backend?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, a user can access the data if you don't require authentication. (Using Endpoints without auth will actually make it easier for someone trying to get to your data because of tools like discovery and the APIs Explorer.) Fortunately, it's not too hard to add auth to Endpoints, see: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth

Comment: I'll study more about the Endpoints and its authentication, and try to implement it in our Backend! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a service account see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2    towards the bottom of the page.

I'm just begining with app engine too so don't take it as gospel.

Comment: I checked this page yesterday, but I'll check it again as recommended!
Thank you!